# Is it possible to compile C++ sources with Clang 3.1 plus VC11 Beta headers?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, clang, visual-c++-2012

I'm trying to compile a fairly simple "hello world" program using stl headers with clang on windows, and I'm unable to do that.

I've compiled Clang 3.1 from repository using VC11 Beta without problems.
Now I'm trying to use the already compiled Clang to compile a "hello world" sample using the VC11 headers but I get a bunch of errors which seems to show Clang is getting lost with some macro magic for simulated variadic templates on VC11, although I'm not making direct use of this macro magic.

My include directories:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt

I get errors like:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef:1094:24: error: '_Nil' does not refer to a value

And a bunch of others related to macros.

Was someone able to overcome this macro issues? Is there a problem with clang preprocessor on expading this macros?

Comment: Macros aside, this won't work as Clang doesn't handle `__declspec`.

Comment: @ildjarn So I think the headers aren't full of __declscpec, with VC10 I was able to compile the same source using iostream header (and other headers from VC10) without problems.

Comment: @Chico: That's because VC10 *understands* `__declspec`. Clang does not.

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry, I meant to say "with VC10 headers". Assume same configuration as the problem presented, only changing compiler versions, and I don't get those problems.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's C++ headers involve extensions and idiosyncrasies that aren't yet supported. Clang can build programs with the C headers on Windows, but not yet the C++ headers.

Since the C runtime works you might be able to use a different C++ standard library that only relies on the C runtime. I haven't tried it, but perhaps libc++ can be used that way.

Comment: I was able to compile with VC10 headers.
First class support for libc++ on Windows is lacking.
If there's some idiosyncrasy, I want to know exactly what one is this.

Comment: @Chico I haven't tried hard, but `clang++ -std=c++11 file.cpp` with the source `#include <vector>` resulted in many errors like `error: unknown type name '__m256'`.

Comment: Well them, maybe I'm with some memory gap... I just remember compiling trivial C++ samples with clang using this headers without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sure you will not be able to use clang for compiling some headers like C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt. The reason is because Windows 8 brings a C++ version with some extension. This version has be called **C++/CX**.

Some of the extensions (like **ref class**) are not standard C++. I believe this is causing messages on building saying you are trying to compile some variadic templates.

Comment: Those extensions related to WinRT are not a problem in this case, I'm not using them, and also, the issue seems not to be related with this. I think I could remove that include directory at all.

Comment: Are you sure none of those extensions are present at the headers? I saw an speech delivered by a guy name Caruth from the clang team and they said clang is not available yet for Windows because of several issues.

Comment: Yes, C++/CX is used in some of the header files, but such usage is always guarded with `#ifdef __cplusplus_winrt`.  Otherwise, the headers would be unusable in any programs that don't use `/ZW`.  Similarly for C++/CLI-specific features in the headers, with the `__cplusplus_cli` predefined macro.  There shouldn't be any issues caused by these language extensions.

Comment: However, there are assuredly other reasons why Clang might not be able to consume the Visual C++ Standard Library headers.  Among other reasons, the headers rely on much Visual C++- and Windows-specific functionality (e.g. compiler intrinsics, nonstandard library functions), and in at least some places the library code may well rely on nonconforming behavior in the Visual C++ compiler.